# Не могу сделать увеличения картинки по клику

Tags: jquery

```js
 $(".mask").click(function(){
        var test = $(".mask").prev();
    
       // var img = test2;
        var src = test.attr("src");
        $(".galary_content").append("<div class='wrap_img_portfolio '>"+"<div class='wrap_bg_portfolio'></div>"+"<img src="+src+" class='me_portfolio_img ' />"+"</div>");
        $(".wrap_img_portfolio").fadeIn(800);
        $(".wrap_bg_portfolio").click(function(){
            $(".wrap_img_portfolio").fadeOut(800);
            $(".wrap_img_portfolio").remove();
        });
    });
```

```html
 <div class="img_content_all">
                              <img src="../Shablon_16/image/image_portfolio/slidepf1.jpg" alt="" class="image_portfolio">
                              <div class="mask">
                                  <div class="plus"></div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
 <div class="img_content_all">
                              <img src="../Shablon_16/image/image_portfolio/slidepf1.jpg" alt="" class="image_portfolio">
                              <div class="mask">
                                  <div class="plus"></div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
 <div class="img_content_all">
                              <img src="../Shablon_16/image/image_portfolio/slidepf1.jpg" alt="" class="image_portfolio">
                              <div class="mask">
                                  <div class="plus"></div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
 <div class="img_content_all">
                              <img src="../Shablon_16/image/image_portfolio/slidepf1.jpg" alt="" class="image_portfolio">
                              <div class="mask">
                                  <div class="plus"></div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
```

И так проблема в следующем! Если брать картинку и добавлять `.click()` на картинку то все работает! Но дело в том что на картинке есть маска hover! Получеться когла кликаю на картинку нечего не происходит так как при наведение его перекрывает слой маска(.mask)! Проблема  следующая , когда я кликаю на любую из картинок всегда появляется 1 как пофиксыть?

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(".mask").click(function(){
        var img = $(this).prev();
        var src = img.attr("src");
        $(".galary_content").append("<div class='wrap_img_portfolio '>"+"<div class='wrap_bg_portfolio'></div>"+"<img src="+src+" class='me_portfolio_img ' />"+"</div>");
        $(".wrap_img_portfolio").fadeIn(800);
        $(".wrap_bg_portfolio").click(function(){
            $(".wrap_img_portfolio").fadeOut(800);
            $(".wrap_img_portfolio").remove();
        });
    });
```

Решил сам проблему переписав код jquery!